# How to instantiate an object that contains a Map instance variable that was instantiated using the map binder in Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

If one object (let's call it **workController**) contains a map of string to handlers (**`Map<String, Handler> handlerMap`**) which is injected to it using the mapBinder inside the Guice module and other instance variables that are also injected. Now, if I want to instantiate workController in my code(let us say that I am creating a provider for **workConsumer**: **workConsumerProvider** that is dependent on **workController** and hence I need to instantiate this and provide workController to the constructor of workConsumer), should I declare the whole map again and pass it to the constructor of workController or is there any other way to go about this?

Consider WorkController.java:

```
public class WorkController implements ActivityController {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

private final Map<String, Handler> handlerMap;

@Inject
public WorkController(final ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                      final Map<String, Handler> handlerMap) {
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    this.handlerMap = handlerMap;
}

public void control() {
//call the handler = getHandler(string usecase)
//call the handler.handle()
}

public Handler getHandler(String useCase) {
    Handler handler = eventHandlerMap.get(useCase);
    return handler;
}
```

To support DI for workController, I have defined the provider for ObjectMapper as follows: ObjectMapperProvider.java

```
public class ObjectMapperProvider implements Provider<ObjectMapper> {

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper get() {
        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

The map is injected inside the corresponding Guice module using MapBinder as follows:

```
public class WorkConsumerModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() { 

       bind(WorkConsumer.class).toProvider(WorkConsumerProvider.class);

       bind(ObjectMapper.class).toProvider(ObjectMapperProvider.class);

       final MapBinder<String, handler> mapBinder = MapBinder.newMapBinder(binder(),
            String.class, handler.class);

       //other bindings for the subject and events to be added here.

       mapBinder.addBinding(UseCaseOne.toString()).to(HandlerImplOne.class);

       mapBinder.addBinding(UseCaseTwo.toString()).to(HandlerImplTwo.class);

    }

}
```

Now, consider WorkConsumer.java

```
public class WorkConsumer {

    @Inject
    public WorkConsumer(final String instanceVariableOne,
                        final String instanceVariableTwo,
                        final String instanceVariableThree,
                        final WorkController workController) {

        final FailureHandler failureHandler = new FailureHandlerImpl();
        final Consumer consumer = new Consumer(instanceVariableOne, instanceVariableTwo, instanceVariableThree, workController, failureHandler);
        consumer.start();
    }
}
```

Now, in order to inject the instance variable strings for this **WorkConsumer**, we create a **WorkConsumerProvider** class: WorkConsumerProvider.java

```
public class WorkConsumerProvider implements Provider<WorkConsumer> {

    @Override
    public WorkConsumer get() {
        final WorkConsumer workconsumer
                    = new WorkConsumer(getInstanceVariableOne(),                                                                                 
                                       getInstanceVariableTwo(),                 
                                       getInstanceVariableThree(),                 
                                       getWorkController());
    return workconsumer;
}

private String getInstanceVariableOne() {
    //return these values based on configs.
}

private String getInstanceVariableTwo() {
    //return these values based on configs.
}

private String getInstanceVariableThree() {
    //return these values based on configs.
}

//This is the place where I have a doubt.
private WorkController getWorkController() {
//Should I declare a new map and populate it again in order to instantiate workController despite having populated it once inside the guice module workConsumerModule.java ?
//I haven't yet populated it here.
    return new WorkController(new ObjectMapper(), new HashMap<String, Handler>());
}
```

}

Comment: I think [some code showing what you have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to achieve your goal would help answering your question.

Comment: Added Code snippets.

Comment: Your example might be simplified, but just so you're aware you don't need `ObjectMapperProvider` as-is. Guice's [Just in Time Bindings](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/JustInTimeBindings) will find and instantiate it for you since it has a no argument constructor without needing a binding or a provider.

Answer (score 1):

You can inject into your Providers so you can inject a fully constructed and instantiated WorkController.

```
public class WorkConsumerProvider implements Provider<WorkConsumer> {

    private final WorkController controller;

    @Inject
    WorkConsumerProvider(WorkController controller) {
        this.controller = controller;
    }

    @Override
    public WorkConsumer get() {
        return new WorkConsumer(
            /* instance variables */,
            controller
        );
    }

    //Your instance variables
}
```

This will cause each `WorkConsumer` to share a `WorkController`.

If you want them each to have a unique `WorkController` you can change the instance variable to `Provider<WorkController>` and inject that. Then use `controllerProvider.get()` in `WorkConsumerProvider#get()`.

[Guice's wiki](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki) has a lot of good information including best practices and examples for different scenarios.